# Pipe text to python script in PyCharm debugger

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I have a python script that is called by piping in text to the script (which in turn reads that text by reading stdin). For example:

```
echo "This is some text" | python myScript.py
```

Is there any way to run this under PyCharm debugger? I can't find a way to "pipe" the initial text in.